# How can I set ip address of raspberry-pi4 in nodejs

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi4

I try to set fixed IP on a raspberry pi 4 with node js and if I run the following script with sudo

```
var networkconfig = require('network-config');
var my_net_cfg = {
    ip: '192.168.1.15',
    netmask: '255.255.255.0',
    gateway: '192.168.1.1'
}

networkconfig.configure('eth0', my_net_cfg, function (err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

I get 'null' on console and the IP doesn't change.

Do I need to disable DHCP or something else on raspbian ??

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, I forgot to force restart eht0 when I set the new ip.

The correct my_net_cfg should be

```
var my_net_cfg = {
    ip: '192.168.1.15',
    netmask: '255.255.255.0',
    gateway: '192.168.1.1',
    restart: true
}
```

Maybe someone else makes the same mistake.